# Let's Encrypt configuration on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

When I run

> ./letsencrypt-auto

I can choose my domains, but in the next step it fails on

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following 'urn:acme:error:connection' errors were reported by
the server:

Domains: xx.co.uk
Error: The server could not connect to the client for DV
```

Does apache needs to be listening on port 443 already or what else could be a problem?

- Apache 2.2, Ubuntu 14 LTS Trusty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just started using Let's Encrypt.  My server runs Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I found it much easier to use Let's Encrypt `certonly --webroot` mode.  Here's an example:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --webroot \
  --renew-by-default --agree-tos \
  --email postmaster@analysisandsolutions.com \
  -w /var/www/www.analysisandsolutions.com/public_html \
  -d www.analysisandsolutions.com -d analysisandsolutions.com
```

Then I edited the relevant virtual host file in `sites-available` to contain:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.analysisandsolutions.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.analysisandsolutions.com/chain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.analysisandsolutions.com/privkey.pem
```

Finally call `service apache2 reload`

I also use the resulting certificate for Postfix SMTP and Dovecot IMAP connections.

I made a [shell script](https://github.com/convissor/call_letsencrypt) to simplify the process.  More details about all of this can be found [on my blog](http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/blog/html/lets-encrypt-ssl-tls-certificates-apache-2-2-postfix-dovecot-ubuntu-12-04.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer.

Yes Apache needs to be listening on 443. Easiest way is to make you domain working with self signed SSL certificate.

Then run

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache
```

And Let's Encrypt does all for you. Amazing!